# Customize the spacing and formatting of back icon and text in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have added a custom image for back button in the navigation bar. Here is the function for setting up my navigation bar.

```
func setUpNavBar() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "BackArrow")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "BackArrow")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)   
}
```

The resulting nav bar with above settings is as shown below.

[image]

Next, I want to increase the spacing between the back icon and the text and also increase the text size (also make it bold). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of the text and make it bold set the title textAttributes:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)], for: .normal)
```

To edit the title offset you can use the following:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -10, vertical: 0), for: .default)
```

Comment: The text formatting is working. However, setting the offset does not show any effect. I have tried different values, yet the text stays at the same position.

Comment: Hm, that is the intended call for changing the position. A quick and dirty way would  be to just add spaces to the text to increase the spacing - self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "       Back"... You could also implement a custom view and then assign it to the "customView" property of the backBarButtonItem.

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation, that function is the intended one but didn't work when i used. I have been using the quick method you have mentioned but with that I get the approximate spacing, that's why i do not want to use it. But for the time being, i am using it. I will try the other method as well.